# Is there an intuitive way to modify and save a stored procedure in VS 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012

The only way I can determine in VS 2012 to open an existing stored procedure for modification and save changes is the following:

1) Manually remove the initial word `CREATE` and retype `ALTER` in its place (every time).

2) From the "SQL" menu, then its "Transact-SQL Editor" submenu, choose `Execute`.

Given that VS2012 is in Release Candidate, I'm certain there will be no fundamental changes along these lines.

And, I understand that from a purist point of view that this is executing a query to change the procedure on the server. But from a usability point of view is there no longer a near-equivalent to a simple `Save` button on a toolbar?  Over the course of day this is a not-inconsequential waste of time and mental focus. I could live with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> but manually editing `CREATE` to `ALTER` every time is ridiculous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take it that you're trying to apply changes to a stored procedure to your database?

You can try the following:
Go to View SQL Server Object Explorer. Right click on the SQL Server node and add your server. Open the database and identify the procedure you need to edit. Double click on the procedure, which opens the CREATE script for the object. Leave the CREATE there and simply modify this and click the 'Update' button. Then select Generate Script or Update database depending on whether you want to apply the changes immediately or generate the script to a query window and apply the script yourself.

If you want to generate an ALTER, you can use the Server Explorer (as distinct from the SQL Server Object Explorer, which is also in the View menu). Add your database to Data Connections. Find your procedure, right click and select Open.

Comment: Thank you David for this answer. I had been using the "Server Explorer" pane and in fact had been unable to add my server, only my data connection. I had tried the "Update" button there but received an error which I did not notate.

In any case, yes, using the "SQL Server Object Explorer" per your recommendation works very well, and the Update button accomplishes exactly what I was asking.

Just now, I went back into the "Solution Explorer" and tried the "Update" button again, and now it is working. However I do prefer using the SQL "Server Object Explorer" that you brought to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can add the procedure to source control, make changes, check in, and publish to your DB. I've never done it, but its talked about in this video:

[SSDT talk at TechEd 2012](http://video.ch9.ms/teched/2012/na/DBI311.wmv)